# Swapping an image onClick with jQuery from 4 buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I've had a look through some other questions and was unable to find a solution. I have four buttons and I want them to change the colour of a dress when you click them using jquery. In Dreamweaver I have managed to sort of get it working but rather than replacing the image it seems to replace the buttons, any advice on where I'm going wrong would be greatly appreciated. I created a jsfiddle of it but that works even less, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/zd72f/

Also sorry for not linking the fiddle properly, hopefully the link I've added will work.

```
<body style="margin:0 0 0 0;">
    <div class="background">
        <div id="index-dress">

    </div>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The inner closing div is missing closing div tag?

Comment: On the fiddle you forgot to load jquery

Comment: Sorry, on the jsfiddle I forgot to select jquery 1.8.3, if you click that on you see the result I currently get. I am new to jquery so again sorry for what I'm sure is a really basic question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include jQuery in your fiddle as well as changing only the `src` of the image  which is placed inside `#index-dress` div:

```
$('#index-dress img').attr('src'........
```

instead of all images like what you're doing at this moment:

```
$('img').attr('src'........
```

Final code should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.buttons').click(function () {
        $('#index-dress img').attr('src', "http://public.layar.com/Customer_Care/Demos/fashion/htmldress/images/scarlet-dress-sized.png");
    });
    $('.navy').click(function () {
        $('#index-dress img').attr('src', "http://public.layar.com/Customer_Care/Demos/fashion/htmldress/images/navy-dress-sized.png");
    });
    $('.purple').click(function () {
        $('#index-dress img').attr('src', "http://public.layar.com/Customer_Care/Demos/fashion/htmldress/images/purple-dress-sized.png");
    });
    $('.yellow').click(function () {
        $('#index-dress img').attr('src', "http://public.layar.com/Customer_Care/Demos/fashion/htmldress/images/yellow-dress-sized.png");
    });
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zd72f/13/)**

Comment: This is perfect, thank you very much, really appreciate your help Felix, Rahil, Adil, Lorenzo and Dave! Felix provided me with the exact answer I was looking for. Not sure if I need to close this thread to say my issue is solved, if so could someone point me to that. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Just add a scope to your jQuery image selector:

```
...
$('img', '#index-dress').attr(..
...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zd72f/14/